# HTML other tags in address tags

Tags: html

I used an address tag to give contact information as you should. However, to make it look a little bit better I used other tags in my address tag, like this:

```
<address>
  <div class="adres-line"><span id="straat">{{ field_straat }}</span> <span id="nummer">{{ field_huisnummer }} {{ field_bus }}</span></div>
  <div class="adres-line"><span id="postcode">{{ field_postcode }}</span> <span id="gemeente">{{ field_gemeente }}</span></div>
  <div class="telefoonnummer">{{ field_telefoon }}</div>
</address>
```

Is this ok or should this not be done?

Comment: Also... whats a telefoon? <(°_°<) _(dutch is funny)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some nested tags are allowed in address tags (`<div>` and `<span>` are OK).
 See here: [MDN: `<adress>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/address).
So your example is valid.

However, you should use CSS `class`es instead of `Id`s, because `class`es are more generic and `Id`s have to be unique.

Comment: Yeah I am using those IDs for something though, but thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

That is 100% your preference, if you like to do it that way you're free to do so :)